# Add the same foreign key to 4 rows Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, phpmyadmin, relationship

I am creating tables in PHPMyAdmin using Laravel Migrations. One of the things that I want to do is have a Question Table and Answers Table where 1 question can have 4 answers (Multiple choice). I want to link the answers and the question with a relationship.

Is it possible to set a primary/foreign key in Laravel in such a way that each time a new Question row is created, the question is connected two 4 answers (when created)?
The rows will be populated manually but they need to be linked.

Is this possible and if so I would appreciate any solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, and here is how
in the file migration of answers, you may add `unsignedBigInteger(question_id)`.

in the model `Question` you may add

```
public function answers(){return $this->hasMany(Answer::class)}
```

in the creation of the answer, you may pass in the request `question_id` that is related to this answer

Is that what are you asking for or I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a common way to do it is to subscribe to the `created` event for the `Question` Model. There are several ways to do this, but I usually either register the listeners on `booted()` in the Model itself or use [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) if I have a lot of event subscriptions going on and want it a little more structured.

You can register a `created` listener in a Model like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Answer;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Question extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(
            function ($question)
                {
                    // This closure will be executed every time 
                    // a new Question instance has been created
                    $question->Answers()->createMany(
                        [
                            ['sort' => 1],
                            ['sort' => 2],
                            ['sort' => 3],
                            ['sort' => 4],
                        ]
                    );
                }
        );
    }

    /**
     * A Question has many Answers.
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function Answers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class)->orderBy('sort');
    }
}
```

In this example, I assumed a `sort` column in your schema just for demonstration purposes. If you don't want to prefill any columns on the new `Answer` instances, you can of course just pass in empty arrays (`[]`) instead.

You can read more about this in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events